# How to populate a ChoiceParameter from a text file in a Jenkins Declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In my Jenkins declarative pipeline I need to grab values from a text file in order to populate my choice parameters.

I came with the following pipeline but parameter fails to display its choice values and show fallback "ERROR" instead.

I can't figure out why this fallback to fallbackScript as buiding the pipeline is a success.

**Source text file**

```
client1 dev
client1 prod
client1 test
client2 prod
client2 test
client3 test
client4 test
client4 dev
```

**Pipeline script**

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

// Source text file
datasource_filepath = '/path/to/my_text_file.txt'
File datasource_file = new File(datasource_filepath)

// Keep only first field and enclose all list elements with double quotes
List client_names = datasource_file
                                    .readLines()
                                    .collect { 
                                            it.split().head() 
                                            
                                          }
                                    .collect {
                                            it.replaceAll(it, "\"$it\"")
                                            }
                                    .sort()

// Function to generate groovy script populating choices into the parameter
String ChoicesScript(List choices){
  return "return $choices"
}

// Generates Groovy script for parameter
String client_name_script = ChoicesScript(client_names)

// Debug output
println 'Client names (' + client_names.getClass() + '):\n\n' + client_names + '\n\n' 
println 'Client names generated script(' + client_name_script.getClass() + '):\n\n' + client_name_script + '\n\n' 

// Choice parameters settings
properties([
    parameters([
        [
            $class: 'ChoiceParameter', 
            choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',   
            name: 'CLIENT_NAME', 
            script: 
                [
                    $class: 'GroovyScript', 
                    fallbackScript: [
                                        classpath: [], 
                                        sandbox: false, 
                                        script: 'return ["ERROR"]'
                                    ], 
                    script: [
                        classpath: [], 
                        sandbox: false, 
                        script:  client_name_script
                    ]
                 ]
         ]
    ])
])

pipeline {
    agent any
stages {
   stage('Build'){
    steps {
       echo 'Building...'
      }
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: It turns out that issue is with script approval with silently block generated Groovy script for choice parameter. After approving this script, it works just fine. Main issue is that when "datasource" text file will change (new entries or entries removed, generated Groovy script signature will change and would be blocked by script security. I'd appreciate workarounds for this serious issue which basically prevent populating choice parameter with external data source and would also prevent any changes event to an hardcoded list of choices!